# Java unable to determine Application class

Tags: java, javafx, native-code

I have developed an application using JavaFx and compiled it to native code using ExcelsiorJet. During compilation everything works fine even when I make test run. But after compilation I am receiving this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: unable to determine Application class
at Unknown.<unknown>(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.<unknown>(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.<unknown>(Unknown Source)
at Unknown.<unknown>(Unknown Source)
```

I can't figure out why? Does anybody met with this kind of issue?

Comment: To create a native application using JavaFX, I would recommend using the built-in ["self-contained application packaging"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGIBBCI) instead of a third-party tool, if possible.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ask the support people from ExcelsiorJet what is going wrong here?

Comment: did u check my answer ? is that working for u r not? please replay or if it is working for u mark it as right ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have accidentally solved this problem. The problem was not in code.

Solution:
When I was configuring ExcelsiorJet to compile, on the "Stack trace support" combobox of the TARGER page I have selected "None" and this was my problem. When I have selected "Minimal" everything worked.

I have no idea why it was not compiling using "None" option.

Answer (score 0):

put this main method in your Appliction Calss. it will run fine.
if you want run without main method, (this e(fx)clipse plugin for eclipse only) install e(fx)clipse plugin and use java 1.8 jdk or in your project facets add javafx

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   launch(args);
```

}